# R: st_distance between points and line identified by a specific ID

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

I am looking for calculating euclidean distance between 2 sf files in R:

- The first one (TRANSECTS) is a network of 8 transects identified by the column 'ID'
- The second one (OBSERVATIONS) are observations made by walking along the 8 transects from the first file. Each observation has a column "Trans" where is reported the ID transect, matching IDs from the table "TRANSECTS".

I would like to calculate the euclidean distance between each observation from the table OBSERVATIONS and the specific line transect where the record has been done from the table TRANSECTS.

I achieved my goal through the following command, but it must have an easier way to do...

Thanks if ever you have a better solution.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#TRANSECTS IMPORT#

TRANSECTS <- st_read(dsn = 'C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/Distance_sampling',layer = '2018_12_05_IKAV_L93')
TRANSECTS<-st_set_crs(TRANSECTS,2154)
TRANSECTS<-arrange(TRANSECTS, id) 

#OBSERVATIONS IMPORT#

DATA1<-read.csv(file='C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/Distance_sampling/IKV.csv',sep = ",", dec = ".")
OBSERVATIONS<-st_as_sf(DATA1,coords =c("X_CHEV","Y_CHEV") )
OBSERVATIONS<-st_set_crs(OBSERVATIONS,2154)

#ST_DISTANCE CALCULATION#

D<-st_distance(OBSERVATIONS, TRANSECTS)
head(D)
Units: [m]
           [,1]       [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]      [,8]
[1,]  231.25374 5262.85379 6109.051 9781.463 3920.827 9121.063 8586.745 11699.683
[2,]  254.69284 5327.11137 6382.810 9921.521 4214.769 8636.904 8020.288 11520.814
[3,]  226.47543 5361.76793 6442.659 9961.020 4281.754 8587.226 7956.365 11508.191
[4,]   75.42924 5134.72507 6198.209 9729.977 4034.177 8478.314 7875.684 11335.406
[5,] 1181.60916   25.19995 2306.999 4586.114 1899.290 4044.081 4150.167  5801.358
[6,] 2376.53730   27.98066 2346.578 3480.811 2776.990 2691.604 3815.701  4219.291


DATA<-bind_cols(OBSERVATIONS, D)
names(DATA)[40:47]=c(1:8) #rename with my transects names

A<-DATA%>%
  filter(Transect==1)%>%
  select(-c(41:48))
names(A)[40]="DIST"

B<-DATA%>%
  filter(Transect==2)%>%
  select(-c(40,42:48))
names(B)[40]="DIST"

C<-DATA%>%
  filter(Transect==3)%>%
  select(-c(40:41,43:48))
names(C)[40]="DIST"

D<-DATA%>%
  filter(Transect==4)%>%
  select(-c(40:42,44:48))
names(D)[40]="DIST"

E<-DATA%>%
  filter(Transect==5)%>%
  select(-c(40:43,45:48))
names(E)[40]="DIST"

F<-DATA%>%
  filter(Transect==6)%>%
  select(-c(40:44,46:48))
names(F)[40]="DIST"

G<-DATA%>%
  filter(Transect==7)%>%
  select(-c(40:45,47:48))
names(G)[40]="DIST"

H<-DATA%>%
  filter(Transect==8)%>%
  select(-c(40:46))
names(H)[40]="DIST"

DATA2<-bind_rows(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)

select(DATA2,40)

Simple feature collection with 75 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 920310.1 ymin: 6614858 xmax: 935200.5 ymax: 6630276
Projected CRS: RGF93 / Lambert-93
First 10 features:
        DIST                 geometry
1  231.25374 POINT (920755.7 6626321)
2  254.69284 POINT (920422.1 6625473)
3  226.47543 POINT (920362.9 6625361)
4   75.42924 POINT (920606.8 6625418)
5   41.56977   POINT (924198 6622891)
6  125.53985 POINT (920795.7 6623698)
7  153.00790 POINT (921983.6 6624313)
8  126.24612 POINT (924282.2 6621614)
9   64.08143 POINT (920310.1 6626538)
10  66.53761 POINT (920563.8 6625667)
```